Windows Explorer Not Responding But Crashes, Fade Black and Open "Please Wait a Moment" Windows 10
I've been having this issue since a few days now and it's really annoying, it started when the media player of windows acted up and was crashing 24/7 and now the file explorer just crashes, it put me in a black screen and then goes to a panel "Please wait a moment" of Windows when it's trying to install something but I have no idea how to fix that or go on that page to fix the issue.
I've tried alot of things, even indexing and it doesn't works.
Does anyone has a solution?
Edit
I've fixed the problem, I reverted my windows update and it now work for now, I'll see if I still have a problem!

Can you please share with us the things that you've tried? List them out in the question to help us understand what not to suggest, and also to give us more information about this issue you are dealing with. With the little bit of info we have right now I'd guess this may be a significant SSD/HDD issue, and it may simply be failing. Knowing what file(s) the media player was playing when things began going wrong would also help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Basically I have that issue that File explorer is searching the files and tries to show a preview or something but it keeps searching and when I click on those said files, File explorer stop responding and crashes then goes into the "Please a moment" windows loading window and goes back to my homepage
A basic list of what i've done before
Clear the cache
Run sfc /scannow
Tried to install ExplorerPatcher (but it crashes cause it can't install)
I restarted my PC just to see if it worked again and it does for like a few minutes until I take a new video or picture.

Welcome to Superuser. A big part of your goal to get good answers depends on having a clear and complete question. This is why I asked you to "List them out in the question...". Use the EDIT button below your question to add the things I've asked, and any other clarifying details other commenters ask you for, to your question, so people with answers don't have to scroll through long comment threads to fully comprehend your problem.

I’m voting to close this question because "I've fixed the problem, I reverted my windows update and it now work for now, I'll see if I still have a problem!". It appears the author resolve the problem on their own.

best thing is to reinstall windows and after this directly install fresh new drivers then direct x and VC_Redist runtime packages for Visual C++ 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015, 2017, 2019, 2021 and 2022 and don't install antivirus and disable windows Microsoft essential. also try to have dual windows.
